Outlook: How to have dedicated background color per mailbox
I'm using outlook for few email account address @mycompany.com, @myprivate-isp-provider.com.
I'm opening a dedicated outlook windows to manage separately the emails.
how to have for instance a background color in black for @mycompany.com, white for @myprivate-isp-provider.com or @gmail.com.
going to File/Options/General/personalize your copy of Microsoft Office is not allowed you to have a backgound color per email box addresses.. (managed in File/Info/account settings)
Thanks for help...

I'm not sure about setting the background, but you can change the font and font color of messages in the message list, based on certain rules.
For Outlook desktop:

Select a mailbox (or a folder within that mailbox)
Open View > View settings > Conditional formatting
Create a new rule. You probably want a rule where the recipient is the email address of the mailbox you selected
Click on the Font button to select a font style and/or color

There seems to be a similar option for the Outlook web version, but I haven't tested that

As i know, there's no such method to set dedicated background color per mailbox. In order to be able to distinguish between accounts more clearly, as a workaround, it is recommended that you try to create a separate Outlook profile for each account.

Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.
